# Excel: How to get column value F at row-index X in other worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I've got an workbook with 2 worksheets. `Persons` and `Company`.

In `Company` there are `Name` and `Lastname` from the contact person, but the **searched E-Mailadress in F** is in the worksheet `Persons`.

So with the function `=1+MATCH(F5;Persons!$A$2:Persons!$A$2448;)` I've got the rowindex with the matching `Lastname`, but I want to write **Persons!F[Rowindex]** in field F5...

I knot that this isn´t possible: `=Persons!F(1+MATCH(F5;Persons!$A$2:Persons!$A$2448;))` , but is there function to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INDEX:

```
=INDEX(Persons!F:F;1+MATCH(F5;Persons!$A$2:Persons!$A$2448;))
```

Answer (score 0):

I often use OFFSET along with MATCH to pull the item I want:

```
=OFFSET(Persons!$F$1,MATCH(F5,Persons!$A$2:Persons!$A$2448,0),0,1,1)
```

Offset takes 5 parameters:
1) is your starting point of reference. Since you want column F, point it to $F$1.
2) the number of rows to offset, -3 would be "UP" 3 rows. 2 would be "DOWN" 2 rows, etc.
3) the number of columns to offset, -3 would be "LEFT" 3 columns. 2 would be "RIGHT" 2 columns, etc.
4) the number of rows to include in the return (ie a range), 1 = 1 cell, >1 is a range of rows.
5) the number of columns to include in the return (ie a range), 1 = 1 cell, >1 is a range of columns.